# Why touches sometimes look like already moved or already ended on_touch_down

Tags: kivy

[MotionEvent](https://kivy.org/doc/master/api-kivy.input.motionevent.html) has `time_start`, `time_update` and `time_end` attributes. I thought they can be used to know if a touch has already ended or not, but it looks like not. Here is the code that can confirm that.

```py
from kivy.app import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder

runTouchApp(Builder.load_string('''
Widget:
    on_touch_down:
        t = args[1]
        has_not_moved = t.time_start == t.time_update
        has_not_ended = t.time_end == -1
        print(t.uid, has_not_moved, has_not_ended)
'''))
```

When I mashed a mouse button, I expected the output to be like this:

```
# I expect there is no False

1 True True
2 True True
3 True True
.
.
15 True True
```

but the actual output was

```
1 True True
2 True True
3 True True
.
13 True False
.
15 False False
.
20 False True
```

Why sometimes `False` was printed? Is there a guaranteed way to know if a touch has already ended or not?

[the source code of MotionEvent](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/input/motionevent.py)

#### environment

- CPython 3.7.1
- Kivy 1.11.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what's going on here because I didn't check the source, but maybe it's something like surprising behaviour happening if you manage to touch and release within the same frame.

> Is there a guaranteed way to distinguish touches?

You get a different touch object for each touch, so they are automatically distinguished.

Comment: > if you manage to touch and release within the same frame.

Comment: Thank you @inclement  > if you manage to touch and release within the same frame.  That makes sense. Before the app handle a touch, on_touch_up may be happend in the low-level layer.    > You get a different touch object for each touch, so they are automatically distinguished.  Sorry I meant "Is there aguaranteed way to know if a touch has ended or not". (edit the post)

Comment: It depends on what you mean by ended, but you can safely assume that you get `on_touch_down` when it ends.

Comment: Sorry again, my explanation wasn't enough. I can't use those touch events, and need to know from just a given touch for a reason. But appearently there is no way.

Comment: I don't understand what your issue is - a touch has started when you get on_touch_down and ended when you get on_touch_up, from that you can do whatever you want. Please provide a full explanation or example of where you need more information but can't get it.

Comment: I can't explain why I can't use touch events because of my language skill. But anyways, thank you for your help :)

Comment: Well, for what it's worth I'm pretty sure what you want is possible and probably easy.